# Undefined reference to procedure defined in the same module

Tags: module, fortran

I am trying to get familiarize with modules in fortran and for that I have created a simple code with module. The source code is attached.

MAIN PROGRAM

```
program main_prog
  use mod_f_g_h
  !
  implicit none
  ! f,g,h,s are defined in mod_f_g_h
  real :: x,y
  !
  ! read x,y
  print *, "enter x and y "
  read*, x, y
  !
  ! check
  if( y == 0 ) then
    print*, "y must be non-zero"
    stop
  end if
  !
  ! print on screen
  print*, '  x   = ', x
  print*, '  y   = ', y
  print*, 'x + y = ', f(x,y)
  print*, 'x * y = ', g(x,y)
  print*, 'x * x = ', s(x)
  print*, 'y * y = ', s(y)
  print*, 'x / y = ', h(x,y)

end program main_prog
```

MODULE

```
module mod_f_g_h
  !
  ! use other modules
  implicit none
  !
contains
  !
  real function s(x)
    implicit none
    real :: x,g
    s = g(x,x)
  end function s
  !
  real function f(x,y)
    implicit none
    real :: x,y
    f = x+y
  end function f
  !
  real function g(x,y)
    implicit none
    real :: x,y
    g = x*y
  end function g
  !
  real function h(x,y)
    implicit none
    real :: x,y
    h = x/y
  end function h
end module mod_f_g_h
```

But when I try to compile and link the code, using

```
gfortran -c mod_f_g_h.f90
gfortran -c main.f90
gfortran *.o -o run.x
```

Got the following error (in last step)

```
mod_f_g_h.o: In function `__mod_f_g_h_MOD_s':
mod_f_g_h.f90:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `g_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think, I have defined all the variables, moreover I am not linking any external library, so I don't know why this error is appearing? Any comment/idea?

Comment: I indented your code to make it more readable. You definitely don't repeat implicit none everywhere. Once per module is enough. Also, the exclamation marks in empty lines do more harm than good to readability.

Comment: I'm just a beginner so not very familiar with good programming practices, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should read

```
real function s(x)
implicit none
real :: x
s = g(x,x)
end function s
```

inside the module.

Further explanation by VladimirF:

> By `real g` you were declaring the function `g` inside `s` as an *external* real function distinct from that one in the module.

Comment: I would add that by `real g` you were declaring the function `g` inside `s` as an *external* real function distinct from that one in the module.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks, I added it to the answer...

Comment: @VladimirF then how does s know what g is? does it go through the module? i'm sorry if my question sounds very primitive.

Comment: The module provides explicit interfaces for all contained procedures.