# Fortran function in a module not found by subroutine in the same module

Tags: oop, fortran, gfortran

I am writing a module in Fortran90, Mainly I defined a function inside the module, and a subroutine that uses the function. Here's an excerpt of the module

```
module Mesh_io
  implicit none
  private
contains
  integer function findkey ( )
    content of this function
  end function
  subroutine getNumber_Mesh ()
    integer :: findkey
    content of the routine
  end subroutine getNumber_Mesh
end module
```

When compiling I get the following output:

```
objects/Main.o: In function `__mesh_io_MOD_getnumber_mesh':
Main.f90:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `findkey_'
```

As you can see the function is contained in the module, but for some reason the compiler can not find it.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23992889/undefined-reference-to-procedure-defined-in-the-same-module?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the declaration of findkey inside the subroutine `getNumber_Mesh()` you are creating a local variable `findkey` that hides the function.

With modules, it is not required to declare the return value of functions (of module functions). Simply removing the declaration should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Alexander Vogt. The usage of modules is really new for me. This feedback really helped.

Comment: As the linker can't find a function `findkey_`, and the desired use of `findkey`, it's likely that other things in `getNumber_Mesh` mean that it is declaring an external function not a local variable.