# How can I adapt such legacy Fortran (f77 like) code to using modules?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a scientific simulation program in Fortran. It uses some f90 syntax/capabilities (mainly direct operations on arrays) but is otherwise architecturally f77, ie it's simply a collection of functions and subroutines, grouped/organized in different .f files according to what general, larger "functionality" or "block" they are a part of.

These files are typically either "libray like" (eg there's a .f which is a collection of subroutines for a given scientific domain, another .f for another scientific domain...) or "functionality"-linked (eg if there is a result used or required by the global program / simulation, that requires some "significant" algorithms or code, then all relevant specific functions / calculations / algorithms required to produce this result will be grouped in the same file).

A typical project like this has about 20-30 such files total. It has worked, and has been continuously developed, fine like that for years (and still does, to be fair). We use gcc/gfortran, usually in its latest available revision.

I am trying to assess how modules could, at least progressively, be introduced/used ; mainly hoping this will allow for some additional compiler optimizations and thus execution time speed-up, although expected better checking is of course also always a positive (we do have / already run global static analyzers on the program of course)).

**At least as a first step and in a "quick win" mindset**, can I "simply"

- keep the physical (eg files) organization as-is
- wrap an existing file with

```
module x

contains

(existing code, eg collection of thematically linked subroutines and functions, here)

end module
```

- add a "use" statement where needed
- make sure these now "modules" are being seen / compiled first by the compiler.

And expect to start benefitting from what modules are supposed to allow for (better compiler optimizations and additional checks) ? It looks like doing this works fine, but is there some additional work required to leverage advantages of using modules ?

Comment: It won't be easy to give very general and useful advice, but we can certainly note that taking a general file and sticking it in a module can [easily fail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23992889/3157076).

Comment: Do you have test data with which you can check the results before and after any mods

Comment: Actually, I did exactly what you are saying just recently. I ran into a lot of instances where I fell foul of your "make sure these now "modules" are being seen / compiled first by the compiler.", because there was so much inter-calling. Then I discovered sub-modules ...

Comment: There are many potential potholes when doing that, but most of them are tractable. The most annoying ones are type mismatchs between the actual and dummy arguments (typically a work array that is declared as `real` in a routine but is of type `integer` in the call). It was very common in old codes, and in practice "it just works". However this is (and has always been) illegal, and it worked because with implicit interfaces the compilers were not supposed to check the arguments (and most of time could not anyway). But once the routine is in a module the compilers have to report mismatches.

Comment: To be more positive this is the basic way out of the 1980s into the modern age, but as others have stated there are potential problems, and a lot depends upon the specific code being operated upon. So it will be a win, but if it is a "quick win" is very problem dependent.

Comment: Thanks all for the info.
@PierU I'm not too worried about type mismatch - I'm the main writer of said code and a) know this is not something I've been doing b) have always used a very old, but great global syntax analyzer that catches such things (but doesn't recognize modules and such, and thus I will have to let go of it...)

Comment: @cup sure no issue there, the code works and has always worked / is reproductible, so just running it and checking the results are identical is fine.

Comment: @lastchance out of curiosity, is there a point in using submodules without also declaring / manually writing interfaces ? (I'm not opposed to progressively manually write interfaces, but it would not be in the "quick win" category anymore)

Comment: Well, submodules was the only way I could get round the tangled web of calling routines between different files. If you are used to coding in C++ and writing headers then it's no big deal to write interfaces. The other advantage I found was that I could swap in different implementation files; (for example I have related sets of code for serial and parallel routines that I could swap in or out depending on whether I had an MPI implementation available).